# What does this tag (<meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width, initial-scale=1”>) do?

Tags: html, css

`<meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width, initial-scale=1”>`

My understanding of what this tag does feels a little foggy. I will describe it and maybe you could amend/add to it.

Phones could ‘lie’ about what what CSS Pixel viewport dimensions is being loaded i.e. it might say 700px wide but it’s actually 300px wide. If a device were to do this, it could lead to the content of the .html page being loaded really small. The above tag has something to do with making sure the device that’s loading the .html page doesn’t lie.

Also, I've been told `intial-scale=1` sets the zoom level to 1 by default. What does this mean?

Comment: [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: it just means, that the page will be rendered at the screens width with a normal zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Without this metatag, your sites responsiveness design will render at the devices default setting - and you don't want this as your site wont look as how you have planned it.  By using the metatag - the site will automatically recognize the devices viewports and scale your site accordingly.